# How to know in which version SQL Server started to support a certain function?

Tags: sql-server, versions

I want to check if the SQL scripts I wrote will run successfully on SQL Server regardless of the SQL Server version (or starting from a certain SQL Server version).

**For example:** how can I check if the following SQL statement will work in old SQL Server versions?

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET TABLE_A.COL_1= TABLE_B.COL_1 
FROM TABLE_A AS TABLE_A
LEFT JOIN
TABLE_B AS TABLE_B
ON (TABLE_A.COL_ID=TABLE_B.COL_ID);
```

Comment: This query will work with any version or Edition, so dont worry.

Comment: @M.Ali I think OP meant this just as an example and might want to check more complex queries.

Comment: @M.Ali Thank you ! Can I ask if this appies for the following too?         INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COLA_ID, COLA_1, COLA_2) 
 SELECT COLB_ID, COLB_1, COLB_2 FROM   TABLE_B;

Comment: @NermeenMattar this will also work in any version or Edition, so dont worry.

Comment: @M.Ali Thank you Sir.

Comment: MSDN states the starting version of each t-sql function and data type. For example, the [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function was introduced in 2012 version, and the [`Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) data type was introduced in 2008 version.

Comment: You can't do to run a query ot its function if it is not supported by your version.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - MSDN is good so long as you're not trying to work with unsupported versions. Of course, my usual reaction in those cases is "upgrade!", but that's not always reality as we find it. E.g. SQL Server 2005 introduced the [xml data type](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170809(v=sql.90).aspx) but looking at the current MSDN page for [xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx) would lead one to conclude it was introduced in 2008.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are correct, of course. good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the compatibility level allows you to "simulate" an older/different version of SQL Server.
So you can change the compatibility level before running you query to determine if a given query will run correctly with a certain version of SQL Server.

Here is the syntax:

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDBname] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = x
```

where x is the compatibility level:

- 140: SQL Server vNext
- 130: SQL Server 2016
- 120: SQL Database
- 120: SQL Server 2014
- 110: SQL Server 2012
- 105: SQL Server 2008 R2
- 100: SQL Server 2008
- 90: SQL Server 2005
- 80: SQL Server 2000

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb510680.aspx) for more details

For example the `string_split()` function has been introduced in SQL Server 2016 (compatibility level 130), therefore running a query containing `string_split()` with a compatibility level lower than 130 would result in an error:

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDBname] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130
go
select value from string_split('1_2_3_4','_')

ALTER DATABASE [YourDBname] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120
go
select value from string_split('1_2_3_4','_')
```

The first query will execute correctly, while the second will give the following error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 Invalid object name 'string_split'.

---

*Edit:* 
As pointed out by Damien_The_Unbeliever in comments there are some limitations with these approach. Each version of SQL Server can support only a limited number of compatibility level values.

According to MSDN  here are supported compatibility level values for each version (more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb510680.aspx#Anchor_1)):

```
+--------------------+--------------------------------------+
|      Product       | Supported Compatibility Level Values |
+--------------------+--------------------------------------+
| SQL Server vNext   | 140, 130, 120, 110, 100              |
| SQL Server 2016    | 130, 120, 110, 100                   |
| SQL Database       | 130, 120, 110, 100                   |
| SQL Server 2014    | 120, 110, 100                        |
| SQL Server 2012    | 110, 100, 90                         |
| SQL Server 2008 R2 | 100, 90, 80                          |
| SQL Server 2008    | 100, 90, 80                          |
| SQL Server 2005    | 90, 80                               |
| SQL Server 2000    | 80                                   |
+--------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

According to this table with the latest versions of SQL Server (2016, 2014) you can go back till SQL Server 2008, but you can't go back to SQL Server 2005 or 2000

Comment: You may need a range of servers if you want to test all compatibility levels though, since e.g. a 2014 (120) server can only do compatibility back to 2008 (100). I think the general policy is that any version can do compatibility back two major versions.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, you are right: probably it is not possible to test all SQL Server versions with this tecnique. Apparently with my SQL Server 2016 instance I am able to go back to compatibility level 100 (SQL Server 2008), but not further.

Comment: @Andrea Thank you! that was so beneficial.